Buck converter frequency CCM DCM
I am trying to design a buck converter. And I was wondering what frequency I should be working on? I made a research and they saying in high voltages you should work with under 500kHz. But I couldn't choose. And Which current mode I should select? CCM or DCM? I chose Rout=220 Ohm as the resistance, but I would be very happy if I could get your help on that matter as well.
Vin = 109V-126V
Vout = 9.6V-12.5V
Iout= 41mA min 58mA max

Any priority to size, cost, efficiency, complexity? EMI?

Yes size cost and efficiency important. Because of this topics I am confused.

I mean... how much? Can you put a number on it? How much budget and development time is there for how small it should be? What is quantity, is it low so that development cost is important or will this be in the millions where significant effort can be spent?

I am a student so I am trying to make cheap efficient small size circuit. As I said I have problem with only frequency and current mode selection. So if I can make it fast it would be great. And thank you for your effort.

@Knoples Is this AC/DC or DC DC?

DC-DC converter.

If this is connected to the mains, I would recommend a moderate switching frequency for EMI reasons. Most small dc-dc converters I have seen for white-goods applications - they deliver a few watts, non isolated - operate in this range. Look at figure 21 of this Viper06 data-sheet. This is probably what you need.

Thanks for your reply. It's not connected to the main. I only have a problem with frequency and which current mod I should select. Thanks for your advice on filtering. I'm sure I'll need it in another circuit.
